# Setting outline-regexp and outline-heading-alist according to major mode

Tags: minor-mode, outline-mode

I have made a minor mode that is supposed to customise `outline-minor-mode`.

```
(defun tematika-tools ()
   "Define Heading Patterns and Levels for different major modes"

   (require 'tematika-elisp)
   (tematika-elisp-launch)

   (require 'tematika-bash)
   (tematika-bash-launch))

;;;###autoload
(define-minor-mode tematika-minor-mode
  "Enhances visibility of heading levels and text emphasis."
  :lighter " Tematika"

  (if tematika-minor-mode

      (progn (tematika-tools)
             (outline-minor-mode 1))

    (outline-minor-mode 0)) )
```

The problem is that I have two files that are loaded, one for `elisp`, the other for `bash`.

```
(defvar tematika-elisp-hglevels
  '( (";;; H1" . 1) (";;; H2" . 2) (";;; H3" . 3) (";;; H4" . 4)
     (";;; H5" . 5) (";;; H6" . 6) (";;; H7" . 7) (";;; H8" . 8) )

  "Set outline levels for standard (canonical) headings.")

(defvar tematika-elisp-mglevels
  '( (";;; M1" . 1) (";;; M2" . 2) (";;; M3" . 3) (";;; M4" . 4)
     (";;; M5" . 5) (";;; M6" . 6) (";;; M7" . 7) (";;; M8" . 8) )

  "Set outline levels for Marginal headings.")

(defvar tematika-elisp-hrklevels
  (append tematika-elisp-hglevels
          tematika-elisp-mglevels)
  "Set the hierarchical levels for outlines in Elisp Major-Mode.")

(defun tematika-elisp-outl ()
  "Recognise elisp outlines and associate corresponding level."
  (interactive)

  (let ( (hrklevels tematika-elisp-hrklevels) )

    (setq outline-regexp
           (concat (regexp-opt (mapcar 'car hrklevels)) "\\>"))
    (setq outline-heading-alist hrklevels)) )
```

I have the same thing for bash except that the outline patterns are different

```
(defvar tematika-bash-hglevels
  '( ("## H1" . 1) ("## H2" . 2) ("## H3" . 3) ("## H4" . 4)
     ("## H5" . 5) ("## H6" . 6) ("## H7" . 7) ("## H8" . 8) )

  "Set outline levels for for command shell outline headings.")

(defvar tematika-bash-mglevels
  '( ("## M1" . 1) ("## M2" . 2) ("## M3" . 3) ("## M4" . 4)
     ("## M5" . 5) ("## M6" . 6) ("## M7" . 7) ("## M8" . 8) )

  "Set outline levels for in Marginalia and levels for command
shell marginal headings.")


(defun tematika-bash-outl ()
  "Recognise bash outlines and associate corresponding level."
  (interactive)

  (let ( (hrklevels tematika-bash-hrklevels) )

    (setq outline-regexp
           (concat (regexp-opt (mapcar 'car hrklevels)) "\\>"))
    (setq outline-heading-alist hrklevels)) )
```

I have a problem devising a scheme that uses `tematika-elisp-hglevels` or `tematika-bash-hglevels` depending upon what type of file gets loaded.  Somehow `tematika-minor-mode` must understand the major mode and use either `tematika-elisp-outl` or `tematika-bash-outl` for setting the outline patterns via `outline-regexp` and `outline-heading-alist`.

Comment: So the question is "how do I detect the major mode?".  If so, the answer is to inspect the variable `major-mode`.

Comment: I think that I need to detect it because if I call `(require 'tematika-elisp)` and then `(require 'tematika-bash)`, the result would be that `outline-regexp` and `outline-heading-alist` would get overwritten.

Comment: But need a good scheme to make this happen.

Comment: This is another basic Lisp question: use a conditional (`cond` e.g.)

Comment: Where would be most convenient to introduce it ? Make a new function   `tematika-outl` to replace `tematika-elisp-outl` and `tematika-bash-outl` ?

Comment: Something likxe this then ?  `(cond ((eq major-mode 'emacs-lisp-mode)`